# How I can populate data in birt report by passing parameters in the URL

Tags: birt, url-parameters

I want to pass the parameters in the URL of the BIRT Report. In my reports there are 3 parameters like StoreId, fromdate and todate. I have also tried to write the code of beforeOpen Script of my dataSet in the Birt. Its is as :

```
var store_id;
var from_date;
var to_date;

store_id = params["Store_id"].value;
from_date = params["fromdate"].value;
to_date = params["todate"].value;

this.queryText = this.queryText+" where STORE_ID = "+store_id+" AND TRANSFER_DATE BETWEEN "+from_date+" AND "+to_date+ "ORDER BY TRANSFER_DATE ASC";
```

And i wrote my URL as :

```
http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=adminMasterTransferReport_new.rptdesign&Store_id=1&fromdate=2014-04-26&todate=2014-06-06
```

At the end of the report I am getting such error :

The following items have errors:

```
ReportDesign (id = 1):
+ There are errors evaluating script "var store_id;
var from_date;
var to_date;

store_id = params["Store_id"].value;
from_date = params["fromdate"].value;
to_date = params["todate"].value;

this.queryText = this.queryText+" where STORE_ID = "+store_id+" AND TRANSFER_DATE BETWEEN "+from_date+" AND "+to_date+ "ORDER BY TRANSFER_DATE ASC";



":
Fail to execute script in function __bm_beforeOpen(). Source:
------
" + var store_id;
var from_date;
var to_date;

store_id = params["Store_id"].value;
from_date = params["fromdate"].value;
to_date = params["todate"].value;

this.queryText = this.queryText+" where STORE_ID = "+store_id+" AND TRANSFER_DATE BETWEEN "+from_date+" AND "+to_date+ "ORDER BY TRANSFER_DATE ASC";



 + "
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Report parameter "Store_id" does not exist..
```

If anyone knows then help me.

Comment: Apparently it should work like this. Try the following: declare each parameter in your rptdesign as report parameter, and create a dynamic text at the beginning of the report to display each of them. Comment this beforeOpen script, and run the report to check if parameters are correctly populated. By the way, for many reasons you should use a beforeOpen script in very last resort, in this example using BIRT query parameters would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @domnique " Create a dynamic text at the beginning of the report to display each of them" .. what does this mean?

Comment: I mean inserting a BIRT dynamic text at the beginning of the report, and set as expression something which allows to control if values are correctly mapped from URL. An expression like: "Parameter Store_id="+params["Store_id"].value

Comment: Thats wat I did earlier. Like I passed my values in the request that is URL and in the script I wrote the params["something"].value which means the same as you saying. Isn't it ?? 

Because with the help of the definign report parameters, I am able to retrieve values but I want like if I have datepicker on my html page so by selecting the fromDate and toDate and in onload function I need to directly pass the value from the datepicker to the URL of my report. So this is scenario and i am stuck .

Comment: I think there is a confusion: defining explicitely a report parameter in the .rptdesign does not prevent you to send it through URL. The script exception clearly shows that a parameter is not recognized,  i was trying to explain how to quickly investigate and fix this kind of error. Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: @Dominique i also face the same issue, send three parameter in URL and just can get one. i try to use the json but still get null by using params["XX"].value

Comment: @PranavJ  I think i got a solution to fix it. In Script i used the code "var httpServletRequest = reportContext.getHttpServletRequest(); httpServletRequest.getParameter("startDate"); ...." and send them to java code "listItems = lineReportService.displayDetail(startDate, endDate, productName);" need help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Report Parameter Name matches the one given in the URL.  You are looking for the Report Parameter named "Store_id" in this script but in the first paragraph of your question you state the name as "StoreId".  I think you need to change the Report Parameter name from "StoreId" -> "Store_id".

Comment: I just wrote that in my first paragraph by mistake, but whatever parameter name I am passing in beforeOpen script same parameter is passed in the URL also.

Main problem is like, its not able to run the script don't know why. Is there any other steps I need to do in eclipse. I have not passed any of the parameters after my select statement and also not using any of the report parameters. Just wrote the above script and apended in the URL. Need help !!!